# Is there a way in Azure Datafactory to pass @item() vaules of For Each activity to activies that are deeper in the context?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there a way in Azure Datafactory to pass @item() vaule of for each activity through if activity to execute pipeline inside true of if activity?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand you want to compare the @item() from some value and if its true you want to go with Execute Pipeline , otherwise nothing .

Yes this should be possible . 
I did added the expression in the If activity and did some quick test .

```
@equals(string(item()),variables('value'))
```

Please do let me know if this works .

Answer (score 0):

Passing value down to activities that are far removed from for each loop can only be accomplished with setting ForEach to **Sequential** and than inside for each setting a variable of a pipeline to value of @item(). After that you can set the dynamic property of what ever is under ForEach activity.